# What process is responsible for media keys in Unity?

Tags: unity, i3-wm, media-buttons

I want to use my media keys when using i3wm.

When I am using Unity, all media keys work. When I use i3 none of my keys work even though they are detected properly by `xev`, so I assume there is some process that runs when I run Unity that handles this. I am running `unity-settings-daemon` but it doesn't seem to control the media keys.

Comment: Open terminal and run the command `xev`. Click in the back outlined box, then press the key. Does it detect it?

Comment: Yes it detects the keys, both in unity and i3 but when using i3 it's ignored and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried making it into a custom shortcut? Co it runs a command you can detect and see of that works?

Answer (score 3):

For me this works with PulseAudio:

```
# volume control
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -- '-5%'
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ '+5%'
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
```

Comment: Thanks for the @DEFAULT_SINK@. (I had to remove the -- to make it work)

Answer (score 2):

i3 doesn't have those keybindings by default. You can add them by editing your `~/.i3/config` file.

E.g. for the volume keys, you can use something like:

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5%
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- -5%
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle
```

Other media key names are:

```
XF86AudioPlay
XF86AudioPrev
XF86AudioNext
XF86AudioStop
XF86HomePage
```

You can assign them accordingly. E.g. I'm using DBus to control Clementine with bindings like:

```
#Pause actually works as a play toggle for MPRIS interfaces.
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec qdbus org.mpris.clementine /Player Pause
```

After assigning the new keybindings, restart i3 with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Why the `-- -5%`? not just `-5%`

Comment: Yes it doesn't have them by default, what process can I start to make unity-settings-daemon manage them or something?

Comment: @simao does putting them in the file he said not work?

Comment: it needs the double hyphen to indicate the end of arguments, as the -5% is no argument, but an option, yet starts with a minus, indicating an argument.

Comment: @the_Seppi ahh, makes sense :)

Comment: Unity settings can't be applied to i3. Unity settings daemon uses the GNOMEy stuff, while i3 uses its config file; they are kinda incompatible and can't be  really combined...

Comment: Why cant they be combined? This used to work before 14.04. Yes this works, but I would prefer the native unity solution, hence my questions

Comment: "Native Unity solution"? i3 is no Gtk-based desktop, so Gtk settings won't apply. Only the settings compliant to the FreeDesktop standard will work.